# bower custom install directory with .bowerrc not working

Tags: node.js, git, npm, bower

I'm having trouble getting `.bowerrc` to change my dependencies directory:

```
mkdir bower-custom-install
cd bower-custom-install
touch .bowerrc
```

Add this to `.bowerrc`:

```
{
    "diretory": "components"
}
```

..then:

```
bower init
bower install angular --save
angular#1.2.15 bower_components/angular
```

I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling bower.

Any idea why bower is not using my `.bowerrc` "components" directory?

[Here's a repo of this project](https://github.com/ryanburnett/bower-custom-install) (minus the `components` folder, which [Git won't let me commit](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F)):

P.S. I'm on OS 10.9.2 with:

```
node -v
v0.10.26
npm -v
1.4.6
bower -v
1.3.1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is "c": try "directory" - you wrote "diretory".

And sometimes, StackOverflow should allow answers shorter than 30 characters (here, technically, it's a one character answer :-)).

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that. Thank you for your help.